# SQL - basic Inner Join query

Tags: mysql

I have 3 **MySQL** tables below which I'd like to join together.

---

**Classes**:

```
CREATE TABLE `library_classes` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

INSERT INTO `library_classes` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Tolkien'),
(2, 'CS Lewis');
```

---

**Sessions**:

```
CREATE TABLE `library_sessions` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `class_id` int NOT NULL,
  `session_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `class_id` (`class_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

INSERT INTO `library_sessions` (`id`, `class_id`, `session_timestamp`) VALUES
(1, 1,  '2023-08-01 15:30:00'),
(2, 2,  '2023-08-02 10:15:00'),
(3, 1,  '2023-08-04 09:30:00');
```

---

**Bookings**:

```
CREATE TABLE `library_bookings` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `session_id` int NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `datetime_submitted` timestamp NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;

INSERT INTO `library_bookings` (`id`, `session_id`, `email`) VALUES
(1, 1,  'jose@gmail.com'),
(2, 2,  'jane@yahoo.com'),
(3, 2,  'john@hotmail.com');
```

---

When `jose@gmail.com` is signed in, I'd like my page to look like the following:

```
Tolkien | 2023-08-01 15:30:00 | CANCEL
CS Lewis | 2023-08-02 10:15:00 | BOOK NOW
Tolkien | 2023-08-04 09:30:00 | BOOK NOW
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imported your data to [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/faadf9/4);

The following query shall get you the expected result.

```
select lc.name, ls.session_timestamp,
if(lb.id is null, 'BOOK NOW', 'CANCEL') as booking_status
from library_classes lc
join library_sessions ls on lc.id = ls.class_id
left join library_bookings lb on ls.id = lb.session_id and lb.email = 'jose@gmail.com'
order by ls.session_timestamp;
```

It gives the expected output as :

```
name        session_timestamp       booking_status
Tolkien     2023-08-01T15:30:00Z    CANCEL
CS Lewis    2023-08-02T10:15:00Z    BOOK NOW
Tolkien     2023-08-04T09:30:00Z    BOOK NOW
```

Comment: @Tushar How do I exclude past sessions?

example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca4103f/1/0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252410/discussion-between-michaelmcgurk-and-tushar).